# Sync database extraction with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hbase, etl, apache-nifi

Lets say you have periodic task that extract data from a database and loads that data into Hadoop.

How does Apache Sqoop/Nifi mantain database sync between the source database (SQL or NoSQL) with destination storage(Hadoop HDFS or HBASE, even S3)?

For example, lets say that at time A the database has 500 records and at time B it has 600 records with some of the old records updated, does it have a mechanism that efficiently knows the difference between time A and time B that only updates rows that changed and add missing rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,NiFi has **QueryDatabaseTable processor** which can store the state and incrementally fetches the records that got updated.

in your table if you are having some **date column** that can be updated when **your records gets updated** then you can use the **same date column** in Max value columns property then processor will pulls only the changes that got made from **last state value**.

Here is the awesome article regarding querydatabasetable processor
https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/51902/incremental-fetch-in-nifi-with-querydatabasetable.html

Comment: Do you know if Sqoop does the same?

Comment: In sqoop if you create sqoop job then only sqoop job will store the state.. when we run again the same job then it will incrementally fetches only the new data after the state.

Comment: If you have a NiFi cluster, you can also use GenerateTableFetch, it works like QueryDatabaseTable but it doesn't execute SQL, it just generates it. Then you can use a Remote Process Group to send the SQL statements back to an Input Port on your same cluster, which distributes the load among the cluster nodes. Then each node could use ExecuteSQL to get a portion of the rows. This is more Sqoop-like, as QueryDatabaseTable needs to run on the Primary Node only and thus does the entire fetch itself.